# How to clean up all the Product Recommendation logs?

Tags: magento2, database, product-recommendation

How to clean up all the register that I have in my database related to the Product Recommendation logs?

Is it something that I can do from my side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can clean up the registers from your side.

Executing the following DB commands, you'll delete some temporary tables that are used to export data to Adobe's service:

```
truncate table catalog_data_exporter_products;

truncate table catalog_data_submitted_hash;

delete from flag where flag_code = 'products-feed-version';
```

You can then watch those tables repopulate with newly submitted data.

Comment: I am not able to see `catalog_data_submitted_hash` table in my database.